# display message with Pines notify with ssjs

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I found this article at Xomino : [pines notify](http://xomino.com/2012/04/24/jquery-in-xpages-7-pines-notify/)

This works fine from csjs for example :

`<![CDATA[$.pnotify({
            pnotify_title: 'Regular Notice',
            pnotify_text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
        });]]>`

How can I use it in an ssjs ? (In the ssjs I 'll decide if it has to be displayed and what the contents of it will be)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csjs` combined with `ssjs` to solve your requirements.

Take a look at the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoForm="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true" dojoTheme="true">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.title = "Title of the dialog"}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dojo.ready(function(){

  dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    // create the dialog:
    myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "#{javascript:viewScope.title}",
        content: "test content",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });

});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>

    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[myDialog.show();]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I would like to fire up the dialog with ssjs not csjs

Comment: You could use `view.postScript("XSP.openDialog('#{id:myDialogId}')")` or 
`facesContext.getViewRoot().postScript("XSP.openDialog('#{id:myDialogId}')");` to open the dialog from ssjs

Comment: When I try this , I'm getting a TypeError : XSP.openDialog is not a function
I would also prefer to fire up the pines notify dialog with ssjs....